# Rails 4, Bootstrap-sass 3: glyphicons not showing in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I've deployed an app on AWS OpsWorks. I can see glyphicons in development, but not in produtcion.

assets:precompile

```
run "cd /srv/www/inreviapp/current && /usr/local/bin/bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production"
```

custom.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap/glyphicons";

...
```

I've also tried putting this in custom.css.scss

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url("fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot");
  src: url("fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff") format("woff"), url("fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf") format("truetype"), url("fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular") format("svg");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
RAILS_ENV='production' rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Do you have other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. Here are some things you could check/try:

- Check your **config/appication.rb** file and make sure you have included all the file extensions for the glyphicons so they get included during precompile.

  ```
  config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif *.woff *.ttf *.eot *.svg)
  ```
- Try changing the relative path you are using ("fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot") to an absolute path.

  ```
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src: url("/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot");
    src: url("/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff") format("woff"), url("/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf") format("truetype"), url("/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular") format("svg");
  }
  ```

  *note: if you're not sure your custom.css.scss is overriding your bootstrap files I would also try doing a global search for "@font-face" and change the glyphicon path referenced in your bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css
- If all else fails try copying the glyphicon files you need from whichever directory they are living now, to **/public/assets/fonts/** and then reference this path.

  ```
  > cp vendor/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.* public/fonts/
  ```

Hope this helps!